# What does the term "crack-a-lacking" mean?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

In the [Gorillaz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorillaz) song [Welcome to the World of the Plastic Beach](http://lyrics.wikia.com/Gorillaz%3aWelcome_To_The_World_Of_The_Plastic_Beach) rapper Snoop Dogg uses the term crack-a-lacking.

I've done some searching and can't find a reliable source for the origin and exact meaning of this term, but there are a few options. The term is not used in any specific context in the song.

Comment: Hah. I have no idea, but I would suspect that it is unique to rapping / black hip-hop culture.

Comment: I think it means that it's hard to rhyme anything with orange.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Urban Dictionary and The Online Slang Dictionary both give a definition for *crackalackin'* as meaning "happening" as in

> What's crackalackin'? [What's happening?]

Probably this is derived from "What's cracking?" which is an older term meaning the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

A fellow African American told me that it is a racial statement against white people.  "Cracker" is often used by African Americans against white people. Much like the "N" word is to them. So, if the party is "Crack-a-Lackin", it means there are no "crackers", i.e. white people, at the party.

I shake my head in disbelief when I hear this term being spoke by kids and in movies while African Americans laugh about it because white people are too stupid to understand it is a racial slur against them.

Comment: Do you have any sources that can be examined apart from your friend?

Comment: Too stupid?  I know what is meant when a black guy calls me a cracker, but I refuse to acknowledge it as an insult.  The word is meaningless to me in that context.  Laugh as much as you like, the joke's on you.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable inference based on cracka-lacking, i.e. lacking crackers, if the person making the inference is unaware of what the word means, which is "happening".

Comment: I just heard someone use this post as evidence that this is racist. Clearly it is not... unless someone comes up with a very good reference.

Answer (score -3):

It is a southern term meaning how are you, what are you you to.

Comment: "What are you you to"?

Comment: What David said: huh? And "how are you" is entirely incorrect.

Comment: @Marthaª I think she means "How are you, what are you up to?", which is pretty much the same as "What's happening?", which is the top-voted answer.